# Spring Security and i18n

Tags: spring, spring-security, internationalization

I have problem with accessing when I change language on page.

Without `.antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()`  doesn't work but with **/login*** is almost ok but when I provide in URL 'http://localhost:8080/login?lang=estest123' or sth not related with i18n after login I receive ??language.change_estest123??.

I tried add `.regexMatchers("^login\\?lang=[a-zA-Z]{2}|^login\\?lang=_{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}").permitAll()` but same result as **/login***.

Is any possible to accessing only for i18n ? in other case providing error? Or maybe another way of configuration for i18n which allows in easy way to provide this?

My web security config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the presence of parameters affect the url parsing for Security? Just use `/login` and it should pass `/login` and `/login?lang=xxx`.

But if you want to use direct mapping in your config you can use both of them: `.antMatchers("/login", "/login*").permitAll()`